# how to generate random distinct variables with certain correlation and r squared from existing column?

Tags: python, distribution

Im trying to create a data frame with distinct distribution of random variables

the choices of the distribution is 1 through 7 and the probability of the choices are as follows:

```
scale = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
prop1 = [.05,.1,.2,.3,.2,.1,.05]
```

I need a sample of 400 observations in my data frame so far

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'student':np.arange(1,401,1), 
                   'Q Output1':np.random.choice(scale,400,p=prop1)}).set_index('student')
```

The first variable is `Q Output1` which uses the scale I made above, now I wish the second variable `Input1` to be a similar distribution of choices 1 through 7, however with a high correlation and high R squared to the first variable?

How would I do this in python?

Comment: Why the `r` tag ? are you looking for a solution using `r` language ? or you confound this tag with the R correlation coefficient ?

Comment: hac005, the [tag:r] tag is for the [R programming language](https://www.r-project.org/), not for a variable named `R` or the R^2 statistic. (If you mouse-over the tags in your question, each comes with a well-written description of its intent. Thanks!)

Comment: opps sorry! didn't know that